# a comparison between LS and cohomological dimension

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rational-homotopy-theory

Let $X$ a simply connected elliptic space. Assume $\pi_\star(X)\otimes\Bbb{Q}$ is concentrated in odd degrees. So, we have $dim~\pi_\star(X)\otimes\Bbb{Q}=TC(X_\Bbb{Q})=catX_\Bbb{Q}$ (ie) the topological complexity and the Lusternik-Schnirelmann category. I want to compare the LS category or the $TC$ with $dim~H^\star(X;\Bbb{Q}).$ I just want an idea if it's possible

Comment: I very much doubt that the dimension of cohomology is greater

Comment: also it is possible to using $nil ker\mu_A$ where $A$ is a CDGA of the rational homotopy type of the space $X$ with multiplication $\mu_A$, because $TC(X_\Bbb{Q})\leq~nil ker\mu_A$

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ has torsion in its cohomology, there’s nothing you can say. If $X$ is simply-connected with torsion free (co)homology then it has a homology decomposition, showing that its cone length, hence category, is at most the number of dimensions with nonzero (co)homology. Thus we can say
$$
\mathrm{cat}(X) \leq   \dim ( H^*(X;\mathbb{Q}).
$$
More can be said with information about the distribution of the nonzero groups (if there's clumping).

Answer (score 2):

The Hilali conjecture is a well-known conjecture in rational homotopy theory, which asks whether the inequality 
$$
\dim \pi_*(X)\otimes\mathbb{Q}\leq H^*(X;\mathbb{Q})
$$
always holds for $1$-connected rationally elliptic spaces  $X$. You ask about the oddly generated case. I believe the Hilali conjecture is still unkown in this generality, but is known to hold if in addition the space is *coformal*, meaning the differential in the minimal model is purely quadratic.

Comment: The Hilali conjecture holds for any coformal space X whose rational
homotopy Lie algebra L is of nilpotency 1 or 2. so coformal under condtion